# How to get data from PUT request using PHP 5.4 on Apache 2.2

Tags: php, apache, put

I've tried all of them methods on could find that have worked for other folks, but with no luck.

Here's my PHP code:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $put_data);
echo "foo is: " . $put_data['foo'] . "\n";
```

No matter what I try, I get 'foo is: '

I'm thinking this is specific to Apache as running the same script on an nginx server shows the expected 'foo is: bar'

Things I've tried with no change in the result:

Changing my Content-Type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Adding a LimitExcept directive to my apache config, like so (yes, I restarted after making the change)

```
<Directory "/MyApp/Directory/">
    Allow From All
    AllowOverride All
    <LimitExcept GET POST PUT OPTIONS DELETE>
        Deny from All
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

Using stream_get_contents like so:

```
$put_data = fopen("php://input", "r");
$data = stream_get_contents($put_data);
echo "data is: " . $data;
fclose($put_data);
```

Here are the response headers:

```
Date: Wed, 11 Jun 2014 04:03:09 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.24 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.24
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 7
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Thanks to any who can offer help.  Pulling what's left of my hair out on this one for hours now.

Comment: Just tested this locally using `curl -X PUT "http://my/test.php" -d foo=bar` on Apache 2.2 with PHP 5.5.7 and it worked just fine. Can you show how you're making the request?

Comment: I've done it a bunch of different ways, but the latest was using the DHC Chrome app, which is specifically built for testing REST APIs. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-rest-http-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm Obviously, I set the method to PUT and have tried various combinations (e.g. foo=bar) in the body of the request.

Comment: Can you try via curl? Use the same command I used above but also add the `-v` flag for extra debugging output. Then, paste the results into your question

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the idea.  I tried and didn't get an errors in the response. Too much in the output to paste here, but some key points are that the request is sent as application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the content length of the request is 7 (which makes sense given I'm sending foo=bar), and the last bit of output is Connection #0 to host api.local.com left intact.  Any clues in there?

Comment: Create a pastebin and link it if you're not keen on dumping it all into your question

Comment: Silly me.  Here it is: http://pastebin.com/dWf9C2nv

Comment: So it says it's sent back 35 bytes of data but where is it? Looks like you've truncated the output

Comment: That's just that hard-coded output I've got setup.  My pastebin example had slightly more characters than what's in my example above ('foo is: '), but when I set it back to that I get a response Content-Length of 7 as expected.

Comment: Even when there's no output for the `foo` parameter, you should at least get 9 bytes. Check your error log and / or enable full error reporting and display and see what crops up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55541/discussion-between-evanmcd-and-phil).

Comment: Try adding this to your directory block: `Script PUT /my/test.php` This routes all PUT requests within the context to that file.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code and it's working fine on my setup which is very similar to yours. The only thing I can think of is this:

> Note: A stream opened with php://input can only be read once; the stream does not support seek operations.

From: http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Try and find a place in your code which is already reading 'php://input'. If you're using a framework of some sort, this would be my guess. I would search the entire project files for "php://input" to find out.

If that doesn't seem to be the case, please pastebin the results of the following:

```
print_r(file_get_contents("php://input"));exit;

var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));exit;
```

P.S.
The rest of the note from the PHP manual website reads:

> However, depending on the SAPI implementation, it may be possible to
>   open another php://input stream and restart reading. This is only
>   possible if the request body data has been saved. Typically, this is
>   the case for POST requests, but not other request methods, such as PUT
>   or PROPFIND.

The SAPI implementation could be the difference between your nginx and Apache behaviours.